# Is this conversion to PDO correct?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am attempting to convert the following code to PDO:

```
    $result = DB::query('SELECT * FROM webchat_lines WHERE id > '.$lastID.' ORDER BY id ASC');

    $chats = array();
    while($chat = $result->fetch_object()){

        // Returning the GMT (UTC) time of the chat creation:

        $chat->time = array(
            'hours'        => gmdate('H',strtotime($chat->ts)),
            'minutes'    => gmdate('i',strtotime($chat->ts))
        );

        $chat->gravatar = Chat::gravatarFromHash($chat->gravatar);

        $chats[] = $chat;
    }

    return array('chats' => $chats);
```

**My FAILED attempt:**

```
    $paramArray = array(
         ":lastID" => $lastID
    );
    $result = DB::query('SELECT * FROM webchat_lines WHERE id > :lastID ORDER BY id ASC', $paramArray);

    $chats = array();
    $chats = array();
    while($chat = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){ //CHANGED THIS PART

        // Returning the GMT (UTC) time of the chat creation:

        $chat->time = array(
            'hours'     => gmdate('H',strtotime($chat->ts)),
            'minutes'   => gmdate('i',strtotime($chat->ts))
        );

        $chat->gravatar = Chat::gravatarFromHash($chat->gravatar);

        $chats[] = $chat;
    }

    return array('chats' => $chats);
```

**EDITED:**

An ajax request is being done in the attempts to receive the information returned from the previous php code. The original source of the non-PDO code can be found here:
http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajax-web-chat-css-jquery/

**QUESTION:** shouldn't `$chat = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` be equivalent to `$chat = $result->fetch_object()`? What could I be doing wrong?

**EDIT 2:**

I have found the following error in the error_log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function
>   fetch() on a non-object in
>   on line 151

It seems that `$result` isn't being seen as an object. The code that defines `$result` as been placed above in both samples. The code for function DB::query() is as follows:

```
public static function query($q, $paramArray=array()){

    $stmt = self::$instance->conn->prepare($q);
    foreach ($paramArray as $key => $value)
    {
        $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
    }
    return $stmt->execute();

    //the older version of this function had this code:
         //return self::$instance->conn->query($q); 
    //but I replaced it with the previous so that I can bind the
    //parameters and prepare the sql statement
}
```

shouldn't `$result` hence be an object? it's returning `$stmt->execute();`

Comment: How is it failing? What is the error?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - failing to execute it seems. I am making an ajax request, and it is never being returned. I also though it might be doing a while loop forever, however if I place a `break;` inside just to test, there is no difference in its execution. However, If I comment out the whole while loop, I do receive the ajax request back. I have a more detailed version here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486665/mysqli-to-pdo-code-conversion though I am attempting to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server? It would've been nice if you mentioned you were attempting this with AJAX in your OP.

Comment: @JayBlanchard sorry for the late ajax information, I edited my question to include it. I am running this on an internal server in my computer (via virtual box) on XAMP, and I am not receiving anything back from the ajax request. I will attempt again to find any errors reported, though I didn't find any initially

Comment: @JayBlanchard I am getting very close. I found an error_log saying `$result` is a non-object. I edited my question above

Comment: @Webeng `execute()` returns only `true` or `false`. It does not return the statement object, so you should not return its value from the `query()` method. You might `return $stmt` to continue using that object, or perhaps more logically, just perform the fetch _inside_ the `query()` method then return that 2D array. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski saved my life bro! That was the problem :). If you write that as an answer, I'll accept  the answer.

Comment: @Webeng Okay, I'll write it up soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not often possible to use PDO as a direct drop-in replacement for older `mysql_*()` code, and some conceptual reorganization is necessary here.

[`PDOStatement::execute()` never returns an object](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) of any type. Rather, its return value is a boolean `TRUE/FALSE` based on success or failure of the SQL statement.

In your previous code, you were returning a result resource from the `query()` method, and later fetching from it, performing additional logic inside the fetch loop. Since `execute()` won't return an object that can be used that way, I would suggest instead performing the complete fetch operation inside the `query()` method then later working with a simple `foreach` loop to make use of the rowset. It is also possible to `return $stmt;` from the `query()` method, but that seems logically muddled.

```
public static function query($q, $paramArray=array()){

    $stmt = self::$instance->conn->prepare($q);
    foreach ($paramArray as $key => $value)
    {
        $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
    }
    // Execute the statement
    $stmt->execute();
    // Then fetch and return all rows as an array of objects
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Then, to make use of the returned rowset, switch your `while` fetch loop for a `foreach` loop:

```
// $result is now an array of objects...
$result = DB::query('SELECT * FROM webchat_lines WHERE id > :lastID ORDER BY id ASC', $paramArray);

$chats = array();
$chats = array();
foreach ($result as $chat){
    // Returning the GMT (UTC) time of the chat creation:
    $chat->time = array(
        'hours'     => gmdate('H',strtotime($chat->ts)),
        'minutes'   => gmdate('i',strtotime($chat->ts))
    );

    $chat->gravatar = Chat::gravatarFromHash($chat->gravatar);

    $chats[] = $chat;
}
return array('chats' => $chats);
// etc...
```

From the code in context, it is hard to tell if you have configured PDO to throw exceptions on failure. I would advise doing so, since by default it will error silently when `execute()` or other methods fail. Where the PDO instance is created, set the appropriate attribute:

```
// Turn on PDO exceptions when the instance is first created
// That may not have been within this class, but difficult to 
// tell from the limited code posted.
self::$instance->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```